# Find the closest distance between points following a set of LineStrings

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have two datasets of Point coordinates (representing electrical installations) and would like to find the closest match between the two datasets following a given set of LineStrings (representing the cables). As an example let's take the following situation:

```
points1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [Point(0,1), Point(3,3)]})
points3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [Point(1,0), Point(4,4)]})
lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [LineString([Point(0,0),Point(0,4)]),LineString([Point(0,4),Point(4,4)]), LineString([Point(2,4),Point(2,0)]),LineString([Point(1,0),Point(3,0), Point(3,3)])]})
```

[image]

Here we can see that red point (0,1) is closest to green point (4,4) when following the lines (distance 7) and red point (3,3) is closest to green point (1,0).

How can I automatically calculate the closest green point for each red point? The lines can sometimes be split into smaller segments like in the example and not all red/green points are necessarily on the endpoint of one of the linestrings.

Comment: Looks like a job for KNN.

Comment: networkx, maybe.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Do you know how to transform this data to a graph where the points are nodes and the lines are the edges?

Comment: This seems like a simple graph problem. Convert the points and edges into a graph and then use one of the shortest path algorithms (Like [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)) to find the closest points. KNN would not work here, as you don't have continuous 2D space, but instead a set of pre-defined paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the graph is a bit tricky, I may be missing some edge cases. Considering intersections between lines is needed. The rest is using A*.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
from itertools import combinations

INF = 10**6

roads = [
    LineString([(0, 0), (0, 4)]),
    LineString([(0, 4), (4, 4)]),
    LineString([(2, 4), (2, 0)]),
    LineString([(1, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3)]),
]
coords = []
for road in roads:
    c = list(road.coords)
    for i in range(len(c) - 1):
        coords.append(LineString([c[i], c[i + 1]]))


reds = [Point(0, 1), Point(3, 3)]
greens = [Point(1, 0), Point(4, 4)]

G = nx.Graph()

nodes = set()
for road in roads:
    c = list(road.coords)
    nodes |= set(c)

for n1, n2 in combinations(nodes, 2):
    for c in coords:
        if (n1 in c.coords or c.contains(Point(n1))) and (
            n2 in c.coords or c.contains(Point(n2))
        ):
            G.add_edge(n1, n2, weight=Point(n1).distance(Point(n2)))

for road in roads:
    plt.plot(*road.xy, color="black")

for red_point in reds:
    plt.scatter(red_point.x, red_point.y, color="red", s=100)

for green_point in greens:
    plt.scatter(green_point.x, green_point.y, color="green", s=100)


def find_shortest(G, p1, p2):
    try:
        start_node = min(G.nodes, key=lambda node: Point(node).distance(p1))
        end_node = min(G.nodes, key=lambda node: Point(node).distance(p2))
        start_node_distance = Point(start_node).distance(p1)
        end_node_distance = Point(end_node).distance(p2)

        path = nx.astar_path(G, start_node, end_node, weight="weight")
        path_line = LineString(path)
        if start_node_distance != 0:
            if path_line.contains(p1):
                path[0] = p1
            else:
                path.insert(0, p1)
        if end_node_distance != 0:
            if path_line.contains(p2):
                path[-1] = p2
            else:
                path.append(p2)
        path_line = LineString(path)
        path_length = path_line.length
        return path_line, path_length
    except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
        return None, INF


def draw(path_line, path_length):
    s_point = path_line.coords[0]
    text_position = (s_point[0] + 0.5, s_point[1])
    plt.plot(*path_line.xy, color="c", linestyle="dashed")
    plt.text(
        *text_position,
        f"Length: {path_length:.2f}",
        ha="center",
        va="center",
        color="purple",
    )


opt_paths = [
    min((find_shortest(G, r_point, g_point) for g_point in greens), key=lambda x: x[1])
    for r_point in reds
]

for path in opt_paths:
    draw(*path)


plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

I opted for the A* algorithm to identify the shortest paths between red and green points on the road network. However, there is a potential issue when red points are positioned in the middle of lines, leading to longer paths than visually apparent. To mitigate this, a custom A* function has to be implemented to calculate and exclude backsteps. In the current example, there is one backstep from (0, 0) to (0, 1), which has to be subtracted in the custom A* function. Overall, the procedure appears to be functioning effectively.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

roads = [LineString([(0, 0), (0, 4)]), LineString([(0, 4), (4, 4)]),
         LineString([(2, 4), (2, 0)]), LineString([(1, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3)])]

reds = [Point(0, 1), Point(3, 3)]
greens = [Point(1, 0), Point(4, 4)]

G = nx.Graph()

for road in roads:
    coords = list(road.coords)
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
        G.add_edge(coords[i], coords[i + 1], weight=road.length)

for road in roads:
    plt.plot(*road.xy, color='black')

for red_point in reds:
    plt.scatter(red_point.x, red_point.y, color='red', s=100)

for green_point in greens:
    plt.scatter(green_point.x, green_point.y, color='green', s=100)

for red_point in reds:
    
    for green_point in greens:
        try:
            start_node = min(G.nodes, key=lambda node: Point(node).distance(red_point))
            end_node = min(G.nodes, key=lambda node: Point(node).distance(green_point))

            path = nx.astar_path(G, start_node, end_node, weight='weight')
            path_line = LineString(path)
            plt.plot(*path_line.xy, color='c', linestyle='dashed')

            path_length = path_line.length
            text_position = (red_point.x + 0.5, red_point.y)
            plt.text(*text_position, f"Length: {path_length:.2f}", ha='center', va='center', color='purple')
        except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
            pass
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have  a question: when I remove the second green point (so greens = [Point(1, 0)]), both red points should lead to the only solution, but the first red point no longer gives a solution. It seems the graph is not completely connected.